# Finding count of some special items in a time range in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Imagine somebody had a mission and the organization is supposed to pay the cost of his meals during the mission but not before of after of that, for instance if he starts the mission after 8 a.m he won't be paid anything.
it will be the same if he finishes the mission after 9 p.m which is not going to be the time of dinner, the lunch time ends at 12:00

here's the table:

```
ID  Date        DepartureTime              breakfast  Lunch  Dinner
1   2018-03-13  2018-03-13 13:12:32.000    True       False  True
2   2018-03-14  NULL                       True       True   False
3   2018-03-15  NULL                       False      True   True
4   2018-03-16  NULL                       True       True   False
5   2018-03-17  2018-03-17 13:00:00.000    False      True   True
```

I need a query in which I could calculate the count of meals that are qualified to be paid for,

I suppose it should be resolved by creating a time range and using `CASE WHEN`

Here True means he had that meal, false means he didn't eat.
The answer should be :

Breakfast : `2` ; Lunch: `4` ; Dinner: `2`

Comment: With that sample data, what is the expected result? Can you also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Makes no sense to me.  VTC

Comment: Why do you vote down when you can't solve it, i explained enough, when you aren't qulified to solve it just leave it alone!!!

Comment: Does DepartureTime mean both a start time (ID = 1) and an end time (ID = 5) of the mission? Why doesn't the departure time match the date on ID 5?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, the start time and the end time of mission a stated by departure time, it's the time he leaves home or finishes the mission.

Comment: The end time was corrected.

Comment: not possible to have 4 lunches from 5 while 2 were done after 12:00

Comment: You misunderstood man, the start of the mission is `2018-03-13 13:12:32.000 ` and the end is `2018-03-17 13:00:00.000`, any meal during this time range is paid for so he can't demand for the first day breakfast since his mission started after breakfast time.
I didn't make this table up by myself, it's what I'm given to work on.

Comment: since `DepartureTime` means nothing for starting or ending or both - you cannot know how to calculate or you need more conditions which nobody aware of;

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
SELECT *
,B=CASE WHEN (cast(DepartureTime AS time) between '00:00:00' AND '08:00:00' OR DepartureTime IS NULL) AND [Breakfast]='True'  THEN 1 END
,L=CASE WHEN (cast(DepartureTime AS time) between '08:00:01' AND '13:00:00' OR DepartureTime IS NULL) AND [Lunch]='True'  THEN 1 END
,D=CASE WHEN (cast(DepartureTime AS time) between '13:00:01' AND '20:00:00' OR DepartureTime IS NULL) AND [Dinner]='True'  THEN 1 END
FROM MissionToEat
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f45fd/2)

Answer (score 0):

1) Link each meal with a time interval (or just an exact time). For example:

- Breakfast: from 8am to 10am
- Lunch: from 12am to 2pm
- Dinner: from 7pm to 10pm

Example here:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MealTime') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #MealTime

CREATE TABLE #MealTime (
    Meal VARCHAR(100),
    StartTime TIME,
    EndTime TIME)

INSERT INTO #MealTime (
    Meal,
    StartTime,
    EndTime)
SELECT
    Meal = 'Breakfast',
    StartTime = '08:00',
    EndTime = '10:00'
UNION ALL
SELECT
    Meal = 'Lunch',
    StartTime = '12:00',
    EndTime = '14:00'
UNION ALL
SELECT
    Meal = 'Dinner',
    StartTime = '19:00',
    EndTime = '22:00'
```

2) Identify if `DepartureTime` represents a start or end for each row, and create time intervals to make step 3) easier:

```
;WITH Limits AS
(
    SELECT
        MinimumID = MIN(M.ID),
        MaximumID = MAX(M.ID)
    FROM
        OperationDetails AS M
)
SELECT
    M.*,
    StartTime = CONVERT(TIME,
        CASE 
            WHEN L1.MinimumID IS NOT NULL THEN M.DepartureTime
            ELSE '00:00' END),
    EndTime = CONVERT(TIME,
        CASE 
            WHEN L2.MaximumID IS NOT NULL THEN M.DepartureTime
            ELSE '23:59' END)
FROM
    OperationDetails AS M
    LEFT JOIN Limits AS L1 ON M.ID = L1.MinimumID
    LEFT JOIN Limits AS L2 ON M.ID = L2.MaximumID
```

3) Count each meal if they were eaten and their time overlap:

```
;WITH Limits AS
(
    SELECT
        MinimumID = MIN(M.ID),
        MaximumID = MAX(M.ID)
    FROM
        OperationDetails AS M
),
MissionTimes AS
(
    SELECT
        M.*,
        StartTime = CONVERT(TIME,
            CASE 
                WHEN L1.MinimumID IS NOT NULL THEN M.DepartureTime
                ELSE '00:00' END),
        EndTime = CONVERT(TIME,
            CASE 
                WHEN L2.MaximumID IS NOT NULL THEN M.DepartureTime
                ELSE '23:59' END)
    FROM
        OperationDetails AS M
        LEFT JOIN Limits AS L1 ON M.ID = L1.MinimumID
        LEFT JOIN Limits AS L2 ON M.ID = L2.MaximumID
)
SELECT
    AmountBreakfastToPay = COUNT(CASE WHEN M.Breakfast = 'true' AND M.StartTime <= BR.EndTime AND M.EndTime >= BR.StartTime THEN 1 END),
    AmountLunchToPay = COUNT(CASE WHEN M.Lunch = 'true' AND M.StartTime <= LU.EndTime AND M.EndTime >= LU.StartTime THEN 1 END),
    AmountDinnerToPay = COUNT(CASE WHEN M.Dinner = 'true' AND M.StartTime <= DI.EndTime AND M.EndTime >= DI.StartTime THEN 1 END)
FROM
    MissionTimes AS M
    INNER JOIN #MealTime AS BR ON BR.Meal = 'Breakfast'
    INNER JOIN #MealTime AS LU ON LU.Meal = 'Lunch'
    INNER JOIN #MealTime AS DI ON DI.Meal = 'Dinner'
```